# Get rid of \addlinespace in kable

Tags: r, latex, knitr, sweave

In a knitr/Sweave report, the `kable` function of `knitr` with the option `booktabs=TRUE` adds a `\addlinespace` each fifth line:

```
P1 & A & 10 & 11.016181 & 110.16181 & 44.95101 & 269.9745\\
P1 & B & 10 & 8.592386 & 85.92386 & 35.06083 & 210.5743\\
P1 & A & 100 & 120.610305 & 120.61031 & 58.61274 & 248.1857\\
P1 & B & 100 & 94.990728 & 94.99073 & 46.16245 & 195.4671\\
P2 & A & 1000 & 698.097191 & 69.80972 & 37.34843 & 130.4846\\
\addlinespace
P2 & B & 1000 & 837.649249 & 83.76492 & 44.81452 & 156.5690\\
P2 & A & 10000 & 10356.365176 & 103.56365 & 49.47422 & 216.7883\\
P2 & B & 10000 & 10214.989594 & 102.14990 & 48.79884 & 213.8289\\
\bottomrule
```

Is it possible to get rid of these `\addlinespace`'s while still using the option `booktabs=TRUE`?

Comment: @Yihui Thank you, this is really generous!

Comment: @CL. I don't care about these virtual points. I don't often start a bounty. When I do, I almost always offer the maximum possible points. You saved me two minutes, and these two minutes are totally worth 500 points.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can add the argument `linesep = ""` to `kable`. This will be passed on to [`kable_latex`](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/f467b6b27e1fee71bf0baa52ba13e048b66a215d/R/table.R#L211) where it overwrites the default

```
linesep = if (booktabs) c('', '', '', '', '\\addlinespace') else '\\hline'
```

Example:

```
kable(cars, format = "latex", booktabs = TRUE, linesep = "")
```

Comment: excelent, I did not know that kable command pass latex commads as is.

Comment: Can I specify, in a vector, how much vertical space I want between each row seperately when working with 'kableExtra' and Latex for creating pdf's? Or is this a question which should be asked seperately?

Comment: Wonder if there's a way to set a default for this.