# Appending blank rows in table using kable function from knitr

Tags: r, knitr, kableextra, kable

The `kable` function from `knitr` **R** package add blank row after every five rows by default.

```
knitr::kable(mtcars, format = "latex", booktabs = TRUE)
```

I wonder if there is a way to change this specification?

Comment: I'm not seeing this default behavior. When I run this line I do not get a table with blank lines. Could you provide example output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get rid of \addlinespace in kable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45409750/get-rid-of-addlinespace-in-kable)