# Controlling row height in kableExtra()

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, kableextra, kable

Hi i made this awesome table with `kableExtra`, but my only problem is that the height of the rows is not always equal. Does any one know a remedy for this?

my table:

[image]

for example, as you can see, the line for item number 22 (6th row) has a larger height (spacing) than other lines.

my code:

```
my_column_names = c("Item number", "Item", 
                "Emotion", "Social", 
                "At Home", "Body", "Emotion", 
                "Social 1", "Social 2", 
                "At Home", "Body") 

kable(df1,
      format = "latex", booktabs = TRUE,
      col.names = my_column_names,
      caption = "Factor loadings for the 4 and 5 Factor Model") %>%
      kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "hold_position"),
                    full_width = FALSE) %>% 
      add_header_above(c(" " = 2, 
                 "4 Factor Model " = 4, "5 Factor model" = 5)) %>%
      add_header_above(c(" " = 2, 
                 "Model" = 9)) %>%
      kableExtra::landscape()
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The reason why the row height is not always equal is that by default `kable` inserts a `\addlinespace` every 5th rows. To get rid of it, put `linesep = ""` in `kable()`. See [Get rid of \addlinespace in kable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45409750/get-rid-of-addlinespace-in-kable) for details.

Comment: Wow, this works, can I also add those spaces (which i now deleted) on certain rows manually? This to make a clearer distinction between groups of items loading on one factor?

Comment: I assume you can but I haven't tried it. You could also use `group_rows` from `kableExtra` but it will insert a label row together with the space you want. :P

Answer (score 2):

Usually, this is something that you can change via CSS in an HTML table. Not sure how to do this with `kableExtra` but you might want to consider `tableHTML` to do it. I am adding a small example below to demonstrate row height:

```
library(tableHTML)
tableHTML(mtcars[1:10, ], 
          border = 1,
          rownames = TRUE, 
          caption = 'This is a caption',
          footer = 'This is a footer',
          widths = c(140, rep(50, 11)),
          second_headers = list(c(2, 5, 6), c('', 'col2', 'col3')),
          theme = 'scientific') %>%
  add_css_row(list('height', '50px'), rows = 3:12)
```

[image]

You don't need to use the scientific theme if you don't want to. The package gives you flexibility to add any css you like (like striped rows, etc.). You can check a tutorial [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tableHTML/vignettes/tableHTML.html) if interested.

P.S. It currently only supports one extra header. Apart from that your whole table can be replicated.

Comment: If you are using Rmarkdown you can knit it as pdf yes.

Comment: Thanks @LyzandeR for pointing me to your package. `kableExtra`-tables usually look odd, when copied to Outlook. `tableHTML`-tables work fine with that Outlook crap.