# Space after every five rows in kable output (with booktabs option) in R Markdown document

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, bookdown, kable

I am using `knitr::kable()` to render tables as part of an **R Markdown** document (that itself is part of a **bookdown** project). In particular, the booktabs option (through setting the `booktabs` argument to equal `TRUE`) renders the table in a nice-looking way. However, I'd like for there not to be a space after every five rows.

Here, for example, is the code and how the table in the bookdown demo appears when rendered as a PDF:

```
knitr::kable(
  head(iris, 20), caption = 'Here is a nice table!',
  booktabs = TRUE
)
```

[image: iris table with booktabs]

I'd like for the space that aappears after every five rows to not be included, but I cannot seem to find a setting in `knitr::kable()` that does this.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The reason why the row height is not always equal is that by default, kable inserts a `\addlinespace` every 5 rows when booktabs is specified as TRUE, as is shown [here](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/R/table.R#L223):

```
linesep = if (booktabs) c('', '', '', '', '\\addlinespace') else '\\hline'
```

To alter this, add `linesep = ""` as an argument to `kable()`.

```
knitr::kable(
  head(iris, 20), caption = 'Here is a nice table!',
  booktabs = TRUE,
  linesep = ""
)
```

[image]

> See [Get rid of \addlinespace in kable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45409750) for more details.

It is also worth saying that you can play around with this option if you want to  change the style. For example `linesep = c("", "", "", "\\hline")` would add a horizontal line every four spaces.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I think the reason why I didn't find that Q&A was that I wasn't searching for \addlinespace.

Comment: Knowing the right search term is always the hardest part :)

Answer (score 10):

Based on the example above I was interested in controlling the separation. That works nicely with the following helper function. This makes it possible to control the locations of the line separation.

```
linesep<-function(x,y=character()){
  if(!length(x))
    return(y)
  linesep(x[-length(x)], c(rep('',x[length(x)]-1),'\\addlinespace',y))  
}
knitr::kable(
  head(iris, 20), caption = 'Here is a nice table!',
  booktabs = TRUE,
  linesep = linesep(c(3,2,1,1,3,5,4,1))
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Bart's answer failed to work for me on my remote server when using prettyNum() on the table and passing the output to kableExtra::kable_styling(), where it just added an column full of NAs and no linespaces. It seems to work fine on my local machine, so I can't reproduce the error.
Anyway, this alternative solution works for me (but only when passing the table to kableExtra for some reason):

```
linesep <- function(table, groups) {
 sep_indx <- rep("", nrow(table))
 sep_indx[cumsum(groups)] <- '\\addlinespace'
 return(sep_indx)
}

knitr::kable(
  head(iris, 20),
  caption = 'Here is a nice table!',
  booktabs = TRUE,
  linesep = linesep(head(iris, 20), c(3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 5, 4, 1))
) %>% kableExtra::kable_styling(latex_options = c("scale_down", "HOLD_position"))
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCnwB.png)