# Most elegant ways to add a few empty rows into a data frame in R?

Tags: r

This is an example of what I want to do:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:100,y=1:100)
empty_row_ids <- c(5,10)
```

This is the final output:

```
results <- rbind(data.frame(x=1:4,y=1:4),c(0,0),data.frame(x=5:8,y=5:8),c(0,0).data.frame(x=9:100,y=9:100))
```

Essentially, I want to insert some empty rows at some given numbers.

Comment: It's very unusual to add empty rows to a data.frame. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Also are you sure you want to add zeros rather than NA values? Do you only have numeric columns?

Comment: I am generating publication-quality regression tables. The results are stored in a data frame, and I need a few spaces between the different categories. I used zeros just for the example, in reality, it will be blank rows.

Comment: "I am generating publication-quality regression tables."  Ideally, this table formatting is something you'd do as a layer on top of your data, not with a manipulation of your data itself.  If you provide an image of the kind of table look you want, it's possible someone can help you find a formatting solution instead of a data manipulation.

Comment: It looks like `kable` has a linespacing option that can be set, see discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49015578/space-after-every-five-rows-in-kable-output-with-booktabs-option-in-r-markdown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do what you want would be formating the `empty_rows_id` inside a dataframe with the zeroes and then use `bind_rows()` in a `dplyr` pipeline to add the data. Here the code:

```
library(dplyr)
#Data
df <- data.frame(x=1:100,y=1:100)
empty_row_ids <- c(5,10)
#Create data for rows
dfindex <- data.frame(id=empty_row_ids,x=0,y=0)
#Now bind
df2 <- df %>% mutate(id=1:n()) %>%
  bind_rows(dfindex) %>%
  arrange(id) %>% select(-id)
```

Output (some rows):

```
      x   y
1     1   1
2     2   2
3     3   3
4     4   4
5     5   5
6     0   0
7     6   6
8     7   7
9     8   8
10    9   9
11   10  10
12    0   0
13   11  11
14   12  12
15   13  13
```

If you want to export to other source to format your tables, it would be better to use `NA` instead of zero as @MrFlick said.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend looking for a formatting solution, rather than one that changes your data.  But you can use [`add_row()`](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/add_row.html) to do what you're asking.

```
library(dplyr)

n <- 2 # number of spacing rows to insert at each point
spacer <- rep("", n)

df %>%
  mutate(across(.fns = as.character)) %>%
  add_row(x = spacer, y = spacer, .before = 6) %>%
  add_row(x = spacer, y = spacer, .before = 11)
```

Output:

```
      x   y
1     1   1
2     2   2
3     3   3
4     4   4
5          
6          
7     5   5
8     6   6
9     7   7
10         
11         
12    8   8
13    9   9
14   10  10
...
```

Insert as many spacing rows `n` as you desire with `rep("", n)` at the target indices.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same but follow a pattern of x times, where x could be the number of times that you want to do it? For example, I want to add 2 rows after 10 rows and do it 5 times

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base R solution

```
add_empty_rows <- function(df, at) {
  new_len <- nrow(df) + length(at)
  result <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) vector(class(x), new_len)))
  result[(1:new_len)[-at],] <- df
  result
}
newdf <- add_empty_rows(df, empty_row_ids)
```

Basically we just make a new data.frame with all blank rows, then put the values we want to keep in the slots we don't want to keep empty

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way manipulating row index :

```
inds <- seq(nrow(df))
df1 <- df[c(inds  - cumsum(inds %in% empty_row_ids), 
            tail(inds, length(empty_row_ids))), ]

row.names(df1) <- NULL
df1[empty_row_ids, ] <- 0
df1

#      x   y
#1     1   1
#2     2   2
#3     3   3
#4     4   4
#5     0   0
#6     5   5
#7     6   6
#8     7   7
#9     8   8
#10    0   0
#11    9   9
#12   10  10
#13   11  11
#..
#..
#99   97  97
#100  98  98
#101  99  99
#102 100 100
```